# Not able to locate an anchor tag that has a pseudoelement ::before inside it using testCafe

Tags: javascript, tags, anchor, pseudo-element, testcafe

TestCafe : I have an anchor tag inside which there is a pseudoelement ::before. How do I select the image which appears inside the anchor tag which appears in the inspect element only when I hover over the ::before element. This is the anchor tag :
`<a class="nav-icon flag gh-desktop-only en-GB" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="langDropdown" aria-label="Language Dropdown">::before</a>.`

I have tried this way but it doesnt work.It says element not visible in Dom:
`const anchorTag = Selector('a.nav-icon.flag.gh-desktop-only.en-GB'); await t.click(anchorTag);`

Please guide on what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue with your example, but I did not manage to. Please note that Testcafe actions can’t target [pseudo-elements](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/element-selectors?search#use-element-selectors-with-actions-and-assertions). 
You can use ClientFunction as a [workaround](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2813#issuecomment-482583471)